# kds with segger - Error while launching command: arm-none-eabi-gdb --version

Tags: c++, c, debugging

I have a Segger and correctly select "Segger"

[image]

yet when I click **Debug**, I get an error.

[image]

NXP support is not helpful: [*make sure you correctly select Seegger*](https://community.nxp.com/message/1118372)

Comment: No hints as to that the error was, I suspect. What happens when you try to run `arm-none-eabi-gdb.exe --version` from the command line?

Comment: It runs fine. I really think it’s a bug in this plugin because that exe isn’t supposed to be run because SEGGER has its own versions of gcc utils.

Comment: Can you point the debugger at it? I remember using segger under eclipse, but something like ten years ago. I had to use a remote launcher that's since been replaced with a much smarter tool that's a lot more limited.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It probably does not know where your gdb is. Set the full path or add the path to the system env.

Comment: And it gave it explicitly: `"C:\Program Files (x86)\CodeSourcery\Sourcery_CodeBench_Lite_for_ARM_EABI\bin\arm-none-eabi-gdb.exe"`

Comment: I also have PEmicro debugger and within KDS and it works fine.

Comment: Yes you're right. I had to hard-code `C:\Freescale\KDS_v3\Toolchain\bin\arm-none-eabi-gdb.exe` to replace their macro.